# Best practice of concurrent http calls and socket connection

Tags: android

I have a app in which there is a dedicated thread that connects with game server with nio socket to exchange real-time data with the server. At the same time, there could be a couple of concurrent threads running, each of which makes a http call (using apache HttpClient) to retrieve a small image from another server.

Now the issue is that, when the image-retrieving http calls are invoked, the socket connection is obviously delayed. I tried adding the following code to increase the priority of the socket thread

`android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_MORE_FAVORABLE);`

but it did not help. I still saw the lag of socket communication.

Do you have any suggestion on this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: How about introducing a load / buffer screen when you have to download bitmaps? Or change your code that your app downloads bitmaps well in advance, also taking probabilities into account, like being in the same level / area / proximity with other entities or players and load and cache everything in advance, even when it won't be used by your app. That way you have these lags under control.

Comment: Unfortunately, the real-time data from socket determines what images to download, so we can not retrieve the images in advance.

Comment: For following that approach you would also need to make changes to the server software of course. When you are triggering multiple downloads of biggish files I don't think that you can expect near real time performance of your socket communication even when you are trying to change the priority (which doesn't seem to work anyway). It is the current protocol of the client-server communication that needs to be fixed.